# What is unidirectional many-to-many association?

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, hibernate-mapping

As far as I understand, `Many to Many` association between 2 entities *A* and *B* mean that *A* can have more than one values in *B* and *B* can have more than one values in *A*.

If that is correct what does `unidirectional many to many association` mean ?  How is it different from `bidirectional many to many mapping` ?

As the name suggests `many to many` means bidirectional !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are getting confused with database tables and its corresponding entities.

From DB perspective: Many to many would be implemented using third table, which holds entries from both the tables.

From java entities perspective: its upto you, if you want it to be bidirectional or unidirectional. What it simple means, is that, you can have a collection of Students in Module, but you may not want to care, to how many Modules student belongs to.

```
class Student{
//attributes and methods
}

class Module{

Collection<Student>  students;

//other attributes and methods.

}
```

Now, being in administration of some institution, I want to have flexibility of creating modules and assigning students to this module. I would prefer many-many unidirectional. So, here actually if you see, there are many modules as well as many students( i hope you can make out what i mean). Having said that, you are not restricted to find out if a Student belongs to Java module or not. I hope it makes it little more clear.

Comment: I understand the DB perspective but not the `java entities perspective`. I am unable to differentiate between the two

Comment: hmm, see my edit, i think it should make you doubt a lot more clear :)

Comment: I have a doubt, can we please discuss here @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32452/discussion-between-suhail-and-zerocool

Answer (score 2):

Unidirectional means that, for example, `A` has a reference to `B`s, but not the other way around.

*many to many means bidirectional* **No**. The `many to many` concept is for database table mapping. Hibernate uses it (and other `x-to-x`) to generate the proper database table schema. The `x-directional` concept is for java objects.

Comment: can you please elaborate this _"..The many to many concept is for database mapping. The x-directional concept is for java objects..."_ I am not quite getting it.

Comment: I meant table mapping. With a `@ManyToMany`, hibernate will generate a third join table with ForeignKeys to the relevant tables. So the annotation is used by Hibernate to generate the correct schema.